# How to avoid maximum recursion depth in python with generators?

Tags: python, recursion, generator, breadth-first-search

I'm finding the shortest path using BFS, I get this  `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison` very quickly, any suggestion on how to avoid it using generators ? Or making it iterative is the only good option?

Code below:

```
def bfs_paths(graph, start, goal):
    queue = [(start, [start])]
    while queue:
        (vertex, path) = queue.pop(0)
        for next in graph[vertex] - set(path):
            if next == goal:
                yield path + [next]
            else:
                queue.append((next, path + [next]))

def shortest_path(graph, start, goal):
    try:
        return next(bfs_paths(graph, start, goal))
    except StopIteration:
        return None
```

Usage example:

```
graph = {'A': set(['B', 'C']),
         'B': set(['A', 'D', 'E']),
         'C': set(['A', 'F']),
         'D': set(['B']),
         'E': set(['B', 'F']),
         'F': set(['C', 'E'])}

shortest_path(graph, 'A', 'F') # ['A', 'C', 'F']
```

Comment: No, I'm talking about using generators to handle them. And this is an example. I'm using the next generator and still I reach the max depth.

Comment: If you are getting this error with small graphs (such as your sample) you have a logic error, not a resource limit. Unless the graph has more than a thousand nodes, it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Your exact program runs on my machine just fine

Comment: @Navidad20 and John: You guys are right about working with small examples. And indeed, it works fine with small examples like these but not with bigger examples.
That's exactly what my question, how do I handle bigger datasets(or graphs in this case) ?

Comment: Could you give a sample graph that breaks for you?

Comment: The line `for next in graph[vertex] - set(path):` guards against cycles, but it doesn't prevent the same node from being visited multiple times (on paths through different intermediate nodes). Perhaps you could maintain a set of visited nodes and only extend paths by previously unvisited nodes.

Comment: @Navidad20 I was facing this issue on a graph with 5k nodes. And finding shortest path is part of the problem. Also, I don't think I can provide the dataset here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. It includes a visited set.  I also modified the variable name 'next' to 'node' as it is a built in function

```
def bfs_paths(graph, start, goal):
    visited = set()
    queue = [(start, [start])]
    while queue:
        vertex, path = queue.pop(0)
        visited.add(vertex)
        for node in graph[vertex]:
            if node in visited:
                continue
            elif node == goal:
                yield path + [node]
            else:
                queue.append((node, path + [node]))

def shortest_path(graph, start, goal):
    try:
        return next(bfs_paths(graph, start, goal))
    except StopIteration:
        return None
```

Comment: Thanks for the try. However, I still get the same error of max recursion depth reached.

Comment: If there was anyway for you to provide some sample data that shows your error, I think it would go a long way to helping someone find you a solution.

Comment: Alrighty, I'm setting up a github repository. Give me 5 mins.

Comment: I found the solution, John and @Navidad20 you guys were right, maintaining the visited reduced the elements being pushed in the stack.
Thank you guys, and sorry for the confusion ! :D